# Compile errors for ruby 2.0.0-p195 on fedora 18

Tags: ruby, rbenv, ruby-2.0

I'm trying to install ruby 2.0.0-p195 on fedora 18 with ruby-build but I get compilation errors as seen in the following log dump. I have openssl-devel, zlib-devel libraries all installed but they arent found for some reason.

http://pastebin.com/mGdR411E

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting is because the user you are running as does not have access to write to `/usr/local/bin` 
(line 796: `/usr/local/bin/ruby (Errno::EACCES)`)
Try using sudo or running as root.